# Express.js large header size 400 bad request

Tags: node.js, express

I use Express.js for project, Node.js version 10.16.3, and when the request headers/cookies are large, Express.js returns 400 bad request.

Would you know how I can increase the size of the header which my Node server can handle?

I tried `http-max-header`, but that doesn't seem to work, and I start https server.

I use `app.get()` methods.

Comment: are you using body-parser?

Comment: @AbhishekPathak Yes I am using it, can I configure using that ?

Comment: are you using nginx as reverse proxy?

Comment: OK. I'm curious. What are you sending in your header?

Answer (score 2):

In the course of this [issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/24692) they've introduced the `max-http-header-size` cli option:

```
--max-http-header-size=size
Added in: v11.6.0, v10.15.0
Specify the maximum size, in bytes, of HTTP headers. Defaults to 8KB.
```

You can use it as follows:

```
node --max-http-header-size=<maxSizeInBytes> your-script.js
```

Comment: See also the following comment on how to configure this option when you create the server, instead of thru CLI (for me was needed because I was using ts-node-dev and it wasn't easy to pass down the CLI arg): https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/4131#issuecomment-565655526